# How to escape spaces in filename when including image in markdown?

Tags: image, jupyter-notebook, escaping, markdown

Working in a Jupyter notebook, I can include images directly in markdown like this:

```
![description](filename.bmp)
```

This does not seem to work if the filename contains spaces:

```
![description](file name with spaces.bmp)
```

Is there a way to escape the spaces in the filename in direct markdown? The following variants do not work:

```
![description]('file name with spaces.bmp')
![description]("file name with spaces.bmp")
![description](file\ name\ with\ spaces.bmp)
![description]('file\ name\ with\ spaces.bmp')
![description]("file\ name\ with\ spaces.bmp")
![description](file_name_with_spaces.bmp)
![description]((file name with spaces.bmp))
![description]({file name with spaces.bmp})
```

I am on Debian 10, by the way, if that matters.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[Use `%20` for spaces](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Percent-encoding#Character_data), e.g.:

```
![description](file%20name%20with%20spaces.bmp)
```